# How to consume external API from WordPress post editor and display the response data in the custom field?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, metabox, api

I am developing a custom post type called "Team," where I will add some profiles of team members. I am using ACF for the custom field to add personal details of the members (I can also implement custom meta boxes to add details, but I found ACF the most straightforward option).

While managing some personal details with ACF, I must get other personal information (e.g., contact information) via an API endpoint. I have to build a field to input members' IDs, and after hitting the submit button, that relevant member's contact details should be displayed in the custom field. I will then save it and manage to display it on the front end.

How can I fetch an external API from the WordPress post editing page and display the response data in a custom field?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: doing this requires you to write javascript and build a block editor side panel, or to modify the blocks edit component. Unfortunately by choosing to use ACF fields you've eliminated the second option and would need to ask in an ACF community how to modify or extend the edit component and autofill the fields for an ACF block. Likewise if this is actually a metabox implemented by ACF then you would need to ask in an ACF community how to fill that ACF fields UI with your data. Also are there any details on the API request itself? APIs work in lots of different ways, there's no 1 size fits all

Comment: @TomJNowell, Thanks for the reply, I will remove the ACF and build the metabox by custom field, so is there any way to display the response data in the metabox field? My plan is to build a single loginID field and a submit button so that response data will show in the metabox after clicking the submit button.

Comment: I wanted to answer similarly, but Tom was quicker. The problem is that it can not be done in PHP, since the whole block editor functions in javascript. Therefore, you should create a block in javascript/WP React environment. Calling external API from block editor is relatively easy, you can just use [apiFetch](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/)

Comment: you can also make the request to the REST API and have PHP contact the API, you don't have to query the API directly in JS, but some sort of JS request is necessary wether it's to your server or to a remote API. The specifics of which one to do will depend a lot on which API you're asking about, it would really help to know what the metabox is meant to do and where the API you're contacting is, keeping things ambiguous/generic hurts your question